# I can't query GQL for 2 properties only wildcard is working

Tags: google-app-engine, go, gql

I store `comment` entity in Datastore and I use `Datastore Viewer` to see stored data.

I can do following queries

```
select * from comment    
select __key__ from comment
select Subject from comment
select Comment from comment
```

But I can't query

```
select Subject, Comment from comment
// Error: The suggested index for this query is:
//    - kind: comment
//      properties:
//      - name: Comment
//      - name: Subject
select __key__, Subject, Comment from comment
// Error: projections are not supported for the property: __key__
```

I can't find any reference why it is wrong. These errors does not tell me much.

I have not set any key or index for these entities.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference) tells following:

```
SELECT [DISTINCT] [* | <property list> | __key__]
  [FROM <kind>]
  [WHERE <condition> [AND <condition> ...]]
  [ORDER BY <property> [ASC | DESC] [, <property> [ASC | DESC] ...]]
  [LIMIT [<offset>,]<count>]
  [OFFSET <offset>]

  <property list> := <property> [, <property> ...]
  <condition> := <property> {< | <= | > | >= | = | != } <value>
  <condition> := <property> IN <list>
  <condition> := ANCESTOR IS <entity or key>
  <list> := (<value> [, <value> ...]])
```

`Subject, Comment` - is property list and it valid query. But it is not.
I created entity from Go code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The projection queries come with some limitations. In the [projection-doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/projectionqueries#Go_Limitations_on_projections) is mentioned that `"Only indexed properties can be projected"`.

The first error message shows exactly that the combined index of `Subject, Comment` doesn't exist yet. You can create the index manually by adding

```
- kind: comment
  properties:
  - name: Comment
  - name: Subject
```

to your `index.yaml` in your project root folder. Please have a look at the [index spec](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/indexconfig) and projection-doc.

```
// Error: projections are not supported for the property: __key__
```

Entity `keys` are returned by the GetAll method. Don't put them in your projection.

```
keys, err := q.GetAll(c, &people)
```

I can't post more than 2 links yet, so please look for more details in the datastore reference.